# Let $G$ be a finite group and $K$ a finite field. There exists $L$ finite field such that $L/K$ is Galois and $\mathrm{ Gal} (L/K) \simeq G$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, finite-fields

My question is

> Let $G$ be a finite group and $K$ a finite field. Is true that always exists another finite field $L$ such that $L/K$ is Galois and $\mathrm{ Gal}\left(L/K\right) \simeq G$?

I tried to solve it or to find a counterexample, but my problem is that I don't know what to do with the general group $G$.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This is not true, since an extension of finite fields always has a cyclic Galois group.

Comment: For you to be able to do this you need $K$ to be infinite (see Vincent's comment). Even so, it is an open question whether this can be done for example in the case $K=\Bbb{Q}$. OTOH, $G$ is a subgroup of the symmetic group $S_n$ for some $n$, and you can find a suitable $K$ with $L=F(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)$, the field of rational functions on $n$ (algebraically independent) variables.

Comment: I think that this exact question has been asked earlier here. Did you look?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Galois group of a finite extension of finite fields is always cyclic, generated by the Frobenius $\sigma : X\mapsto X^q$ if $K\cong\Bbb F_q$. So any noncylic group $G$ cannot be obtained as $\operatorname{Gal}(L/K)$ for $L/K$ a finite extension of finite fields.

Comment: more details here [Frobenius_endomorphism#As_a_generator_of_Galois_groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_endomorphism#As_a_generator_of_Galois_groups) the Frobenius endomorphism is $F : X \mapsto X^p$, it belongs to $Gal(\mathbb{F}_{p^e}/\mathbb{F}_{p})$ but not to $Gal(\mathbb{F}_{p^{ef}}/\mathbb{F}_{p^e})$. Now $F^e$ belongs to $Gal(\mathbb{F}_{p^{ef}}/\mathbb{F}_{p^e})$, and Its order is $f$. So $Gal(\mathbb{F}_{p^{ef}}/\mathbb{F}_{p^e}) = \langle F^e \rangle \simeq C_f$

Comment: @user1952009 the element $x\mapsto x^q $ in $\operatorname{Gal}(\Bbb F_{q^n}/\Bbb F_q) $ is also commonly known as the frobenius, through it is not the same as the over $\Bbb F_p $

Comment: **as the one over $\Bbb F_p$.

Comment: And once we know that [$\mathbb{F}_{q}^\times$ is cyclic](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/54735/collecting-proofs-that-finite-multiplicative-subgroups-of-fields-are-cyclic) with $q-1$ elements, we have that $X^{q-1} = 1$ and one element has order $q-1$, so that the order of the Frobenius is $n$, and that any automorphism of $\mathbb{F}_{q^n}$ is of the form $X \mapsto X^{l}$, with $p | l$, and $q | l$ if it is fixing $\mathbb{F}_{q}$